# Call to a member function createData() on null using middleware on Laravel Transformers

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, transformer-model

So i created a controller for authentication with 2 methods (`token()` / `native)_`). Im using fractal transformer to return response. The token method works fine for me, but the `loginAndroid()` returns

> "Call to a member function createData() on null" error.

Any help? Thank you.

```
class AuthController extends RestController
{
    protected $transformer = UserTransformers::Class;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('auth:api', ['except' => ['login', 'loginAndroid']]);
    }

    public function login(Request $request)
    {
        $credentials = $request->only(['username', 'password']);

        if (!$token = auth()->attempt($credentials)) {
            return response()->json(['error' => 'Unauthorized'], 401);
        }

        return $this->respondWithToken($token);
    }

    public function loginAndroid(Request $request)
    {
        $credentials = $request->only(['username', 'password']);

        if (Auth::attempt($credentials)) {
            //$user = Auth::user()->with(['employees']);
            $userdata = User::with(['employees', 'employees.role', 'employees.branch'])->find(Auth::id());
            //$success['token'] =  $user->createToken('MyApp')->accessToken; 
            //return response()->json($userdata, 200); 
            //return $userdata;
            $response = $this->generateItem($userdata);

            return $this->sendResponse($response, 201);
        } else {
            return response()->json('gagal', 401);
        }
    }
}
```

this is my restcontroller

```
abstract class RestController extends Controller
{
protected $manager;

protected $transformer;

public function __construct()
{
    $this->manager = new Manager();
}

protected function generateItem($model, $transformer = null)
{
    if (!is_null($transformer)) {
        return new Item($model, new $transformer);
    }

    return new Item($model, new $this->transformer);
}

protected function generateCollection($model, $transformer = null)
{
    if (!is_null($transformer)) {
        return new Collection($model, new $transformer);
    }

    return new Collection($model, new $this->transformer);
}

protected function sendResponse(ResourceInterface $data, $status = 200)
{
    return response()->json(
        $this->manager->createData($data)->toArray(),
        $status
    );
}

protected function sendNotFoundResponse($status)
{
    return response()->json($status, 404);
}

protected function sendIseResponse($status)
{
    return response()->json($status, 500);
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like your `sendResponse()` method depends on `$this->manager`. However, `$this->manager` gets set in `RestController::__construct()` and you've overridden the `__construct()` method in your `AuthController::__construct()`. So, in order to have `$this->manager` available, you should call the parent constructor from your AuthController, like this:

```
class AuthController extends RestController
{
    protected $transformer = UserTransformers::Class;

    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct(); // call the parent constructor where
                               //  $this->manager gets initialized
        $this->middleware('auth:api', ['except' => ['login', 'loginAndroid']]);
    }

... etc
```